# MongoDB - Why does the _id index not throwing an error on duplicate entries?

Tags: mongodb, unique-index, nosql

I'm completely new to NoSQL databases and I'm working currently with MongoDB.

I'm trying to understand why the default `_id` index does not throw an error, when `upserting a duplicate _id` document.

As stated in the docs `_id` is an unique index by default

(although it doesn't show the unique flag here..)

```
> db.foo.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.foo"
    }
]
>
```

So when `upserting` the document (started with an empty collection),
if first inserts it and then seems to "ignore" it.

```
> db.foo.update({ _id: 'doe123'}, { _id: 'doe123', name: 'John Doe'}, { upsert: true});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 1, "nModified" : 0, "_id" : "doe123" })

> db.foo.update({ _id: 'doe123'}, { _id: 'doe123', name: 'John Doe'}, { upsert: true});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

So I've tried another thing and created an `unique index` on "name".

The result of upserting a duplicate name:

```
> db.foo.update({ _id: 'foo456'}, { _id: 'foo456', name: 'John Doe'}, { upsert: true});
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: name_1 dup key: { : \"John Doe\" }"
    }
})
```

Why am I **not** getting this kind of error on a duplicate `_id`?

---

**EDIT**: I'm using MongoDB v.3.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to show duplicate index error in the first case as it is just trying to update the `_id` and `name` fields of the same record with the same value.

If you will try

```
  db.foo.update({ _id: '1098'}, { _id: 'doe123', name: 'John Doe'}, { upsert: true});
```

you will get error, as query is trying to update record with different `_id` with some existing `_id` value.

In second case, you created a record first with `name` field and then you are trying update the same name in another record, which will give error as `name` is unique index.

Edit :-

If you are trying

```
 db.foo.insert({ _id: 'doe123', name: 'John Doe'});
```

will give you the error, as in this case you are trying to insert a record which is already present i.e. `_id` is unique and you are trying to create one more record with same `_id` value.

> `upsert:true` :- if upsert is true and no document matches the query criteria, update() inserts a single document.
>
> If upsert is true and there are documents that match the query criteria, update() performs an update.

Comment: I tried some things around and I got the exception/error I've expected using **insert** instead of **upsert** : `"E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: _id_ dup key: { : \"doe123\" }"`. So why does insert throws me the error, but upsert doesn't? Just because it looks up *"Do I have to update something? No? Well than I do nothing"* ?

Comment: `upsert : true` means it will insert, if field is not there, else it will just update the value. In case of `insert` it will try to insert the record, which is actually having duplicate value for `_id`. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: So it's basically "overriding" the _id *'doe123'* with itself, if a record already exists with this _id?

Comment: Could not understand your question. Can you make it clearer?