# MongoDB duplicate index does not throw error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to MongoDB and trying to make MongoDB throw an error when I insert another document with the same index. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348087/mongodb-why-does-the-id-index-not-throwing-an-error-on-duplicate-entries) MongoDB should throw an error.

The steps I did are:
1.) Add an index to Name field. I verified that it is added:

```
> db.room.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.room"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "Name" : 1
                },
                "name" : "Name_1",
                "ns" : "test.room"
        }
]
```

2.) I tried to add document with the same name and was able to add it:

```
> db.room.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-02-12T10:59:35.394Z"),
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-02-12T10:59:35.394Z"),
        "Name" : "Sample"
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-02-12T10:59:39.474Z"),
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-02-12T10:59:39.474Z"),
        "Name" : "Sample"
}
```

I am using C# MongoDB Driver 2.4.

Comment: How do you create index? I guess indexes are not unique. See how to enforce unique index and try again.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify that the index you are creating is unique, otherwise MongoDB will not enforce it. You can do that with the C# driver using the `CreateIndexOptions` class.

```
roomCollection.Indexes
    .CreateOne(
        Builders<Room>.IndexKeys.Ascending(r => r.Name),
        new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true });
```

Note that index creation will fail if there are currently duplicate names in the collection.